# interactive menu completion inserting common prefix in zsh

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

In my `.zshrc` I have

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

zstyle ':completion:*' menu yes select interactive
zstyle ':completion:*' insert-unambiguous yes
```

My *desired* behavior is the following: suppose I have a folder with `fileA.txt`, `fileB.txt`, `something.txt`. Then the interaction should work like this

```
> ls f<TAB>
```

results in

```
> ls file█
interactive: file[]
fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

Whereas I get the correct options (`fileA.txt` and `fileB.txt`) but the common prefix is **not** inserted (i.e. I'm still at `> ls f█`).

Unfortunately `insert-unambiguous` seems to be ignored with `interactive` switched on. If I switch it off the *entire* first option is inserted, which is something that I don't want.